# How to read environment variable key and value dynamically in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js

I would like to read all the environment variables `key` and `value` dynamically and form the array like below:

```
environment: [
    {
        name: 'DB_NAME',
        value: 'myDatabase'
    },
    {
        name: 'DB_USER_NAME',
        value: 'admin'
    },
    {
        name: 'DB_PASSWORD',
        value: 'admin'
    },
    {
        name: 'DB_TABLE_NAME',
        value: 'myTable'
    },
]
```

I'm able to print all the environment variables but I'm struggling to get the key and value and form the array dynamically - could someone please help me with this? Appreciate your help in advance. Thanks.

```
const env = require('dotenv').config();
var environmetList = process.env
console.log("printing env variables", environmetList)
const environment = [];
```

Comment: What is `process.env` and what happened to `env`? Is `process.env` an object containing the system environment variables or an array of objects with settings?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using [`Object#entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries), get the list of pairs in `process.env`. Then, iterate over it using [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to get a list of objects with `name` and `value`:

```
Object.entries(process.env).map(([key, value]) => ({ name: key, value }))
```